# General Python Question - how to unwind scrambled data

Tags: python

I'm a novice in Python and I'm having trouble with reading the API content and then looking in which dictionary and which list the information I want is in, etc. Is there an easier way than printing out elements down until you find the piece of data you want?

For example. I am trying to get to this element `{'name': 'Famagusta District', 'lang': 'en'}`

From this monstrosity:

```
{'address': 'Ammochostos', 'bbox': [33.548065185546875, 34.959442138671875, 34.590553283691406, 35.690277099609375], 'class_description': 'country, state, region,...', 'code': 'ADM1', 'confidence': 1, 'continent': 'EU', 'country': 'Cyprus', 'country_code': 'CY', 'country_geonames_id': '146669', 'description': 'first-order administrative division', 'dstOffset': 3, 'feature_class': 'A', 'geonames_id': 146615, 'lat': '35.33333', 'lng': '33.86667', 'ok': True, 'population': 46629, 'raw': {'timezone': {'gmtOffset': 2, 'timeZoneId': 'Asia/Famagusta', 'dstOffset': 3}, 'bbox': {'east': 34.590553283691406, 'south': 34.959442138671875, 'north': 35.690277099609375, 'west': 33.548065185546875, 'accuracyLevel': 0}, 'asciiName': 'Eparchia Ammochostou', 'astergdem': 133, 'countryId': '146669', 'fcl': 'A', 'srtm3': 134, 'countryCode': 'CY', 'adminCodes1': {'ISO3166_2': '04'}, 'adminId1': '146615', 'lat': '35.33333', 'fcode': 'ADM1', 'continentCode': 'EU', 'adminCode1': '01', 'lng': '33.86667', 'geonameId': 146615, 'toponymName': 'Eparchía Ammochóstou', 'adminTypeName': 'district', 'population': 46629, 'wikipediaURL': 'en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Famagusta_District', 'adminName5': '', 'adminName4': '', 'adminName3': '', 'alternateNames': [{'isPreferredName': True, 'name': '파마구스타 구', 'lang': 'ko'}, {'isShortName': True, 'isPreferredName': True, 'name': 'Ammochostos', 'lang': 'en'}, {'name': 'Ammóchostos', 'lang': 'el'}, {'name': 'Ammochostos District', 'lang': 'en'}, {'name': 'Eparchía Ammochóstou'}, {'name': 'Famagouste', 'lang': 'fr'}, {'isShortName': True, 'name': 'Famagusta', 'lang': 'en'}, {'name': 'Famagusta District', 'lang': 'en'}, {'name': 'Gazi Magosa İlçesi', 'lang': 'tr'}, {'name': 'Gazimağusa', 'lang': 'tr'}, {'name': 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Famagusta_District', 'lang': 'link'}, {'name': 'Magosa İlçesi', 'lang': 'tr'}, {'name': 'Q59148', 'lang': 'wkdt'}, {'name': 'Αμμόχωστος', 'lang': 'el'}, {'isPreferredName': True, 'name': 'Επαρχία Αμμοχώστου', 'lang': 'el'}], 'adminName2': '', 'name': 'Ammochostos', 'fclName': 'country, state, region,...', 'countryName': 'Cyprus', 'fcodeName': 'first-order administrative division', 'adminName1': 'Ammochostos'}, 'rawOffset': 2, 'srtm3': 134, 'state': 'Ammochostos', 'state_code': '01', 'state_geonames_id': '146615', 'status': 'OK', 'timeZoneId': 'Asia/Famagusta', 'timeZoneName': 'Asia/Famagusta', 'wikipedia': 'en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Famagusta_District'}
```

So Far I went so already 3 levels down but 4th layer seems to have at least dozen elements and `AlternateNames` is not one of them so it's at least 1 more level down.

```
print(row['features'][0]['properties'])
```

I am using Pycharm. Is there any way to view this with indentation or search function? If not what is the easiest way to read the elements down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what name you have given to your dictionary. I have copied the text above and assigned it to a dictionary called 'dict1' for the purposes of showing you this answer.

```
dict1 = {'address': 'Ammochostos', 'bbox': [33.548065185546875, 34.959442138671875, 34.590553283691406, 35.690277099609375], 'class_description': 'country, state, region,...', 'code': 'ADM1', 'confidence': 1, 'continent': 'EU', 'country': 'Cyprus', 'country_code': 'CY', 'country_geonames_id': '146669', 'description': 'first-order administrative division', 'dstOffset': 3, 'feature_class': 'A', 'geonames_id': 146615, 'lat': '35.33333', 'lng': '33.86667', 'ok': True, 'population': 46629, 'raw': {'timezone': {'gmtOffset': 2, 'timeZoneId': 'Asia/Famagusta', 'dstOffset': 3}, 'bbox': {'east': 34.590553283691406, 'south': 34.959442138671875, 'north': 35.690277099609375, 'west': 33.548065185546875, 'accuracyLevel': 0}, 'asciiName': 'Eparchia Ammochostou', 'astergdem': 133, 'countryId': '146669', 'fcl': 'A', 'srtm3': 134, 'countryCode': 'CY', 'adminCodes1': {'ISO3166_2': '04'}, 'adminId1': '146615', 'lat': '35.33333', 'fcode': 'ADM1', 'continentCode': 'EU', 'adminCode1': '01', 'lng': '33.86667', 'geonameId': 146615, 'toponymName': 'Eparchía Ammochóstou', 'adminTypeName': 'district', 'population': 46629, 'wikipediaURL': 'en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Famagusta_District', 'adminName5': '', 'adminName4': '', 'adminName3': '', 'alternateNames': [{'isPreferredName': True, 'name': '파마구스타 구', 'lang': 'ko'}, {'isShortName': True, 'isPreferredName': True, 'name': 'Ammochostos', 'lang': 'en'}, {'name': 'Ammóchostos', 'lang': 'el'}, {'name': 'Ammochostos District', 'lang': 'en'}, {'name': 'Eparchía Ammochóstou'}, {'name': 'Famagouste', 'lang': 'fr'}, {'isShortName': True, 'name': 'Famagusta', 'lang': 'en'}, {'name': 'Famagusta District', 'lang': 'en'}, {'name': 'Gazi Magosa İlçesi', 'lang': 'tr'}, {'name': 'Gazimağusa', 'lang': 'tr'}, {'name': 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Famagusta_District', 'lang': 'link'}, {'name': 'Magosa İlçesi', 'lang': 'tr'}, {'name': 'Q59148', 'lang': 'wkdt'}, {'name': 'Αμμόχωστος', 'lang': 'el'}, {'isPreferredName': True, 'name': 'Επαρχία Αμμοχώστου', 'lang': 'el'}], 'adminName2': '', 'name': 'Ammochostos', 'fclName': 'country, state, region,...', 'countryName': 'Cyprus', 'fcodeName': 'first-order administrative division', 'adminName1': 'Ammochostos'}, 'rawOffset': 2, 'srtm3': 134, 'state': 'Ammochostos', 'state_code': '01', 'state_geonames_id': '146615', 'status': 'OK', 'timeZoneId': 'Asia/Famagusta', 'timeZoneName': 'Asia/Famagusta', 'wikipedia': 'en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Famagusta_District'}
```

Running `dict1` alone will allow you to view how this looks in a much neater way. (I'm using Google Colab)

[image: This image shows a cell in Google Colab with the dictionary displayed in a neater format.]

If I then run this line, it returns the data you are interested in:

```
dict1['raw']['alternateNames'][7]
```

This works because you must return the elements within the outer dictionary, and inner dictionaries. Once you reach 'alternateNames', you can find the information you want using list indexing.

Comment: Thanks. But I mean, what is your method of doing it? Staring at the wall of text looking for { or [ is painful to my eyes.

Comment: Sorry, I have just edited my answer to show how I can see this more easily. By calling the dictionary, I can view it in a neater format, which makes finding the inner dictionaries much easier :)

Comment: Thank you very much! You saved my eyes! :)

Comment: Okay I assume you're not using Pycharm but Jupyter Notebook or something else as "dict1" doesnt show anything. Printing results in the same wall of text.

Comment: Yes, I am using Google Colab.